# App always crashes when I call download manager in adapter class on my actual phone but works perfectly in an emulator

Tags: java, android-adapter, android-download-manager

This is the code for calling download manager in an onclick listener.

````
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(userMessageList.get(position).getMessage()));
                            String nameOfFile = messages.getName();
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "documents");
                            if (!f.exists())
                            {
                                f.mkdirs();
                            }
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
                            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            downloadManager.enqueue(request);```
````

Comment: What is error/crash message?

Comment: Hi, it would be good if you added the error message (use `adb logcat` if you need to).  Also, External Storage has permissions, have you asked for that? What versions of Android are the device and the emulator running?

Comment: Kk, my phone is using android 7 and emulator is version 5.1 and I have already asked for internet, read and write permissions from external storage which are outside <application > in manifest.

Comment: Did you get a fix for this, even I am getting this kind of issue